# share a directory in my container to my machine

Tags: linux, docker, macos, ubuntu

I built a docker image with the following docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git build-essential libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev gawk flex gettext wget unzip python3 python3-distutils python3-setuptools python3-dev libssl-dev && \
    apt-get install -y clang bison g++ gcc-multilib g++-multilib rsync file && \
    apt-get install -y ccache ecj fastjar java-propose-classpath libelf-dev libncursesw5-dev python2.7-dev subversion swig time xsltproc

# Clone OpenWrt repository

RUN git clone https://git.openwrt.org/openwrt/openwrt.git /root/source

RUN cd /root/source && \
    ./scripts/feeds update -a && \
    ./scripts/feeds install -a

# Change working directory
WORKDIR /root
```

then I wanted to share the content of `/root/source` to my machine in order to have access to the `/root/source` directory from my machine and I can browse it and edit it. So I run the docker with the following command:

```
docker run -it -v "$PWD/Shared":/root/source my_openwrt.docker
```

but when I tried to access to the directory `/root/source` I found it empty.
and if I run the docker with

```
docker run -it my_openwrt.docker
```

I can see the content of the /root/source

How I can share the content of `/root/source` to see it from my machine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only map directories from the host into the container. Not the other way around.

When you do `-v "$PWD/Shared":/root/source`, you map the contents of the host `Shared` directory into the container. Since the directory is empty on the host, it also becomes empty in the container. In effect, it hides the contents of the `/root/source` directory in the image.

One way to get it to do what you want is to first copy the contents of `/root/source` to `Shared` using

```
docker run -v "$PWD/Shared":/destination my_openwrt.docker cp /root/source /destination
```

That will copy the contents of the `/root/source` directory to the `Shared` directory on the host.

Then you can run the container like before. But since the `Shared` directory now contains the files from `/root/source`, you can see the files in the `Shared` directory on the host. And if you modify any files, the changes will be visible in the container.